# C# using an Access View instead of a custom query

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, sql-view

PREFACE: There are a lot of questions on SO that relate to "C# using SQL Views" but I have yet to find anything close to my issue.

I'm using C# (Visual Studio 2015) to create an Excel 2010 plug-in. In the back-end I'm required to use Access 2010. I created a View in Access that requires one parameter to be passed.

Instead of typing up the entire query in `command.CommandText`, I would like to simply just use the view and bind the single parameter that it needs to run

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

```
private void getJobSetpoints(int xID, int xYear)
    {
        //string yearTable = "tbl_points_table_" + xYear.ToString();            
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.CommandText = "qry_setpoints";  //**This is wrong, I just don't know how to identify the VIEW.
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = xID;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `command.CommandText = "select * from qry_setpoints"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use view like table.

```
command.CommandText = "select qry_setpoints where ID = @ID";  
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = xID;
```

Comment: right - only if it were a stored procedure and not a view query, OP code would have been fine (except that they would set CommandType to adCmdStoredProc).

Comment: Thanks guys. Something so simple I just couldn't see it :)